# how to load dynamodb table with AWS Glue ETL

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

A simple way to load dynamodb table with AWS Glue is to load with Glue Crawler.
This is described in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simplify-amazon-dynamodb-data-extraction-and-analysis-by-using-aws-glue-and-amazon-athena/
Now I'm wondering if there is a way to load dynamodb table with AWS Glue ETL directly, say, without AWS Glue Crawler. I don't find any related topic so anyone could help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Finally found connection_options works without a crawler.

```
ddb_table = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options = {"dynamodb.input.tableName":"table_name", "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent":"0.5"}
)
```

Comment: Do you know what format it's expecting the data to be in? I am reading a CSV and trying to insert into DynamoDB.  I have tried DynamoDB JSON with both "Items" as root and without "Items". I keep getting `ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`.  I have both hash key and range key as attributes in the JSON.

Comment: Sorry Saurabh. My case is to read from the DynamoDB table but not to the DynamoDB table.

Comment: Thanks anyway. The solution was to not send DynamoDB JSON, rather a plain JSON and let Glue figure it out.

Comment: When I follow the above steps I also get an error `An error occurred while calling o134.pyWriteDynamicFrame. The provided key element does not match the schema`